# Does Apple AdServices provide attribution analytics from within the App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I've been reading through the documentation about [AdServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ad_services) and I think I understand how to pull attribution data using their REST API.

However, I am surprised that I don't see any indication that Apple actually provides this data in its App Store Connect's Analytics dashboard.  Is that the case or am I overlooking something?
Are 3rd party MMP (Mobile-Measurement-Partner) platforms or rolling your own analytics the only two options for iOS developers?